Like exchange property
I’m selling my condo and buying my parents house in irrevocable trust. Parents house appraised at 765,000. I’m going through 1031 exchange. I’m getting loan for amount at 765,000 minus proceeds from exchange. Total amount of 765,000 will go into parents trust account with Ein. The proceeds in trust, my share, can I use after close of exchange to refinance and gap my mortgage to the new exchange? Is using my share taxable or step up and does it void 1031?

It's hard to understand what you're describing. How's irrevocable trust related to you? What's stepped up and why? What are you exchanging?

I'm not sure what "buying my parents' house in irrevocable trust" means. It sounds like there are multiple separate transactions here. First, you are buying your parents' house from them. Then they are setting the money aside in a trust so it will eventually come back to you. You haven't told us what the terms of that trust are, so we don't know when "eventually" will be. Then you have a question I'm not understanding which seems to presume that you can immediately spend the trust --probably not true -- to something to an "exchange", whatever that is...?  Complicated and I don't see why.

Numbers related to the rental property you are selling is important. You have to remember to invest all the net equity in the new place.

@keshlam the exchange part is a mechanism where legally it is as if you exchange one investment property for another so that you don’t have to pay capital gains tax (yet). In reality you sell one and buy the next one but it is done in manner and within a time frame that legally it is treated as if you exchanged the properties. Look up “Starker exchange” if interested.
